# Erro Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, debug

Tempo atrás eu instalei um plugin que permitia programar Swift no Windows, mas depois eu desinstalei o plugin e agora dá o erro da imagem quando clico em "Start" (usando C#):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei deletar a pasta "ComponentModel" que vi em algum site mas não houve efeito; já reparei o VS 2015 mas não ajudou; já desinstalei e instalei novamente o VS 2015 mas não ajudou.

Mas o diretório existe e o programa funciona quando executo fora do VS.

Não sei mais o que eu faço.

Comment: Depois de várias tentativas eu dei um jeito. Graças a mim.

Comment: Poste a sua solução em forma de resposta para ajudar outros colegas quando enfrentarem o mesmo problema. Caso seja um erro seu mesmo (digitação ou configuração errada), considere até apagar seu post.